# Sencha CMD and homebrew's phantomjs

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, homebrew, sencha-cmd

I have a Ruby on Rails project were I use phantomjs, which I installed with homebrew.

Recently, for another project I'm working on I had to install the Sencha Cmd. It seems that the Sencha Cmd comes with its own phantomjs binary.

Now my Rspecs specs are failing with this error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
Errno::EACCES:
   Permission denied - /Users/javi/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45/phantomjs
```

However if I run `which phantomjs` I got `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` which points to `../Cellar/phantomjs/1.9.2/bin/phantomjs`, so it should be ok.

I've tried to reinstall phantomjs but didn't work.

Also I tried to edit my .bash_profile and change the order of $PATH from

```
export PATH=/Users/javi/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45:$PATH
```

to

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/javi/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.1.45
```

but that didn't work.

The only solution I got so far was to uninstall SenchaCMD, however that's not a feasible solution since I have to work in both projects in parallel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error says PERMISSION denied... so do you simply need to change the permissions on the binary, or use "sudo"?

Comment: I'm afrid that's not the question, the question is how to avoid RSpec using the Sencha's phantomjs binary and use the Homebrew one instead.